# Python/ spyder new installation breakpoints not being hit, plus 'sitecustomize' opening on every .py run

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda

I just installed the Anaconda distribution of python, 32 bit. I can execute code in an interpreter, but when working with files, there are some quirks that I can't find answers to thus far. My breakpoints aren't getting hit. Hitting 'debug file' (control + F5) just seems to execute the whole script. At the end of its run, a new file is opened, 'sitecustomize.py.'

Are these issues familiar to anyone? I know it's a noob question, but I can't find a duplicate issue anywhere, and some of the possible nuances of python configurations have eluded me thus far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not alone, this problem is frequently reported, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/list).

I installed the latest version of Python(x,y) and the version Spyder included is 2.2.5 (the latest official release), which having the same bug you reported. Then I manually upgrade the package to 2.3.0beta, then the problem is solved. You can download the version [here](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads) and install from source, good luck!